# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a horizontal scroll view with 3 views. The first view (far left) is a map view. The functionality I want is that the user can only go to the second view by swiping from the far right edge, because I want other gestures to manipulate the map. But, from the second and third view, they may move left or right by swiping anywhere on the view. I have searched how to do this and have had no luck with my specific situation.

I am not sure where to start so if someone could just point me in the right direction that would be great.

So far I have tried:

disabling scrolling while on the first view and adding in the code:

```
let edgeRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: firstView, action: "goToSecondView:")
    edgeRecognizer.edges = .Right

func goToSecondView(){
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.scrollView.contentSize.width/3, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y)
}
```

Comment: The question is a little bit vague. You've tagged with both [tag:swift] and [tag:objective-c], in what language is your scroll view implemented. Also please show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I don't mind solutions in either language, I can translate it. I have not tried anything because I am not sure where to put the ScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer so I am not sure where to start.

Comment: u have 3 views horizontally or vertically ?@EthanSchatzline

Comment: looks like you need collectionview!!!!

Comment: So basically you have nothing, and expect for someone to give you the code. Or you need advices about the placement of the `UI ScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`. Either way, please update the question as in the current form is either unclear, or too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`, let's just make the map view not see touches close to the right edge of the screen. That way the touches will pass through to the scroll view's `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Here's my setup:

[image: storyboard layout]

(Note: the view frames in the picture do **not** match the constraints.)

I have a scroll view containing three “page” views. Page 1 (“MapHolder”) contains the map view as a subview. Page 2 (“Pink”) and page 3 (“Green”) just have label subviews, and have a background color to make them easy to see.

The view sizes are constrained as follows:

- Pages 2 and 3 are constrained to have the same width and height as the root view (which is the superview of the scroll view). This means that each of them will fill the screen.
- Page 1 (“MapHolder”) is constrained to have the same height as the root view, but is constrained to be the width of the root view minus 44.
- The map view is constrained to have the same top, bottom, and leading edges as its parent, but to have the same width as the root view.

So notice that the map view is wider than its parent (page 1). The page 1 view has “Clip Subviews” turned off (this is the default), so the part of the map that falls outside of the page 1 view will still be visible, but won't receive touches.

The view positions are constrained as follows:

- The scroll view has constraints on all four edges to the root view. This means the scroll view will fill the screen.
- Page 1 has constraints from its top, bottom, and leading edges to the scroll view.
- Page 2's leading edge is constrained to page 1's trailing edge plus 44.
- Page 3's leading edge is constrained to be equal to page 2's trailing edge.
- Page 3's trailing edge is constrained to be equal to the scroll view's trailing edge.
- The vertical centers of pages 1, 2, and 3 are constrained to be equal.

The constraints from the page views to the scroll view control the scroll view's `contentSize`.

Finally, I turned on “Paging Enabled” for the scroll view. Result:

[image: demo]

I've uploaded my storyboard [to this gist](https://gist.github.com/mayoff/b1a09e00b360f3b2a0ef). Just put it in a fresh project (replacing the existing Main.storyboard) and link with MapKit to try it out.

Comment: 1 for being so descriptive. Going to try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I am currently trying this and am getting the map showing up with 44points of white space on the right. Clipping is turned off on the mapView's view. I do not have my storyboard set up like yours, I have a view Scroll View Controller and then 3 other View Controllers in my storyboard where I put their views inside the scroll view. So I am not sure how to do the constraints like you said and I'm guessing that's why it is not appearing as yours does. I set the mapView.view.frame = the rootView with -44 to the width and the mapView.MKView's frame.width = the rootView's width.

Comment: I have achieved it by going to the MapViewController in storyboard and just making the MKView's width constrained to the mapView's width+44.

Comment: So now when I do things with the map like go to a certain lat,long, do I need to somehow calculate it to show the map to the left an extra 44 pixels so that the map pin that it zooms into is centered?

Comment: No, just calculate it to be in the center of the map view like normal.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. If my Screen1 has a mapview but also has a button on the top left and top right corners, will the top right button not trigger any actions since it is past the view's frame?

Comment: Yes, that will be a problem. You can use a more deeply nested view hierarchy to fix it.  Make a full-width page view with buttons and map container subviews. The buttons can overlap the map container without being subviews of it. Make the map container 44 points narrower than the page view.

Comment: Thanks! makes sense. And I marked correct obviously. Thanks again for the super detailed explanation.

Comment: and just by the way that also worked. Have a viewcontroller with a Main view, then a subView that holds an MKMapView. worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

Really simple just put this Delegate function on your  `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` and set the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Working with Xcode 8 and Swift 3 :)

You need this 3 delegate functions.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive press: UIPress) -> Bool {
    return false

}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```